# Old KB articles on MSDN

Tags: documentation

Microsoft removes KB articles when they get old.

Its really frustrating to come up to a page for a KB article you know should exist, (you bookmarked it) but its just been removed.

Does Microsoft put them anywhere we can get at them, or are they just completely hidden?

Comment: To clarify: Microsoft removes KB articles when a product reaches end of lifecycle. This is done on a first come first serve basis however.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of an old KB article that has been removed?

I've seen the opposite problem - very old KB articles that pop up in Internet searches. People don't always realize they're looking at something very old, and will sometimes follow ancient advice.

Comment: For instance, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q183107/ was an entry on WM_MOUSELEAVE, but its gone without a trace now from the Microsoft kb article set

Comment: Speak Japanese at all? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183107/ja

Comment: Here is one: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301464/how-to-use-simple-asp-code-to-password-protect-your-asp-pages  look down the page for the reference to 299987 How To Use Database and ASP Sessions to Implement ASP Security. 

You click on that 299987 link and its a not found situation at Microsoft Support. However, if you search for "How To Use Database and ASP Sessions to Implement ASP Security" at that same page, the first result shows the link to the article which is missing.